# Side to side, not up and down

Tags: code-golf, binary-tree

## Task

Given a list of nodes representing a binary tree of positive integers serialized depth-first, return a list of nodes representing the same tree serialized breadth-first. To represent an absent child, you may use `null`, `0`, `'X'`, `Nothing`, `[]`, or any other value that is distinct from your representation of a node's value, which can be represented by an integer or an integer in a singleton list or other collection.

For example, here is an example tree :

```
         1
      /     \
     /       \
    5         3
   / \       / \
  #   4     10  2
     / \   / \ / \
    4   6 #  # #  7
   /\  /\         /\
  # # #  #       #  #
```

Serialized depth-first, this would be `[1, 5, #, 4, 4, #, #, 6, #, #, 3, 10, #, #, 2, #, 7, #, #]` (here, `#` indicates that a child does not exist). This list was made using a pre-order traversal (add a node's value to the list, serialize its left child or add `#` if it doesn't exist, serialize its right child or add `#` if it doesn't exist).

Serialized breadth-first, this would be `[1, 5, 3, #, 4, 10, 2, 4, 6, #, #, #, 7, #, #, #, #, #, #]` (you may trim as many of the `#`'s at the end as you want, I just wanted to make them explicit). Here, you write the root node's value, then the values of all the nodes on the level below, left to right (with a `#` where a node doesn't exist), then values of the level below, until all the nodes are added to the list.

## Test cases

```
[1] -> [1, #, #] //or [1], whatever you wish

Tree: 1   //or just 1
     / \
    #   #
([1, #, #] and [1, #] yield the same result as above)

[100, 4, 5, #, #, #, #] -> [100, 4, #, 5, #, #, #]
Tree:    100
        /   \
       4     #
      / \
     5   #
    / \
   #   #

[10, 5, 2, 2, #, #, 2, #, #, #, 4, 8, 4, #, #, #, 1, #, #] -> [10, 5, 4, 2, #, 8, 1, 2, 2, 4, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
Tree:     10
        /    \
       5      4
      / \    / \
     2   #  8   1
    / \    / \  / \
   2   2  4  # #  #
  /\  /\  /\
 # # # # # #

[100, #, 4, 5, #, #, #] -> [100, #, 4, 5, #, #, #]
Tree:    100
        /   \
       #     4
            / \
           5   #
          / \
         #   #
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

<sup>Brownie points for coming up with a better name for this question</sup>

Comment: shouldn't your second test case be `[100, 4, 5, #, #, #, #]` instead of `[100, 4, 5, #, #, #]`?

Comment: @Jakque Yes, it should, sorry for all the errors.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 194 bytes

```python
def f(x):
	c=x[:1]+[0]*3
	for k in x[1:]:
		p=-(k<1)or[k,0,0,c];c[1+(c[1]!=0)]=p
		if k:c=p
		while k<all(c[2:4]):c=c[3]
	while c[3]:c=c[3]
	q=[c]
	for x in q:
		if-1!=x:x,*w,_=x;q+=w
		print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU7RbsMgDHxOvsJNXqChEzTdJtHyJQhNEQsqAiUkyhb29Rmh62TrdOc72Q4/y30c2m377A0YFDEvCy2i5Ew1kqpjWxZmnMGBHSBKxlXyiyBOyN0YHmfpCE2l1VVL1qAE6iAoViKkmDXguM50vVvfg7t13qfQmV8UTo6WrSr/vJ3/jyYhtXpcjvvlied1J3YQkUdyXMmHiNepEev@zWyHJX2@GdR/dx7ZIXwtCL/MffCd7lFVVwQqWmGMN8kIvBKoCVxy17nfnqQlwOhTnDO@P6T6BQ)

**-24 bytes thanks to Jakque**
**-35 bytes thanks to ovs**

Very bad solution, but it implements the task directly and shouldn't be extremely inefficient at least. It basically deserializes iteratively by just taking each element and storing a current list maintaining `[value, left-child, right-child, parent]` (since Python handles recursive lists perfectly fine), and then re-serializes using a trivial queue method.

Commented and ungolfed version:

```python
def f(x):                                            # Accept a list with null values as 0

	c = [x[0], 0, 0, 0]                          # Maintain current list [value, left child, right child, parent], starting at the root

	for k in x[1:]:                              # For each element after the first
		p = k and [k, 0, 0, c] or -1         # p is the child - if the value is null, -1, otherwise, another 4-list of the right format
		a = c[1] != 0                        # a is true if and only if the left child is already taken
		c[1] = [p, c[1]][a]                  # if the left child isn't taken, set the left child, otherwise, leave it
		c[2] = [c[2], p][a]                  # if the left child is taken, set the right child, otherwise, leave it

		if k < 1:                            # if this is a null value
			while c[3] and c[2] != 0:    # so long as both children are full
				c = c[3]             # step back up once

		else:                                # if this isn't a null value
			c = c[1 + a]                 # descend to the new child

	while c[3]:                                  # as long as this isn't the root
		c = c[3]                             # step up (this just goes to the root)

	q = [c]                                      # start a queue with just the root
	for x in q:                                  # keep going through the queue
		print(x == -1 and -1 or x[0])        # if the current value is -1, output it, otherwise, you get a 4-list, and output the value from it
		q += x != -1 and x[1:3] or []        # if the current value is -1, nothing, otherwise, add the left and right children to the queue
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRLc9owED6TX7GBQ@2J6UBI2xlPOfTSW3@BxwfFXmPHwjKyHODX091VeCUkIYx5CFvfY7X7tVtXmma22@VYQBFswhi@8BrBnyzD1oECXXUO1pUroem1hmele@xAdTC5uRlkMIdkk0zSCCb@Sj8C/aeqxtEbst5abJwHTwQzAo2Fg6ysdB6BrRblYdEqfpg4Oqesq5oFKAeuRLDGOFJRGAs1EOwmmcZp/Jm1v/Q4qqwE1LhkFapwaAWwqGznbgaDlnzVoJocknpvLUuBNo6nJ0gtVJ3sE6EwhqqQpRjie1yyiPZEYOh/u6468qkaWcDDWOwbv8c7JitLxQoUKciSaQq3c5i870WJAstsheg1jd7uZRwLyk8pbVHlW3CqxoYYBJ2Or42EKE1UeonhElbzzXkYOhJ0r@6fedWonkmbE7574eNvOtOv8L0mO@uOS2xERzg1/IZp/HEzCB0xcIFOOpwABmvCp6NNZqlUVvTzacR@Z2dAG@7FDh5Jg5dDjQrUrVAQEmPIhAjEOW3nsIVHldXQt3RmGbJk1B3Gn4/mUTKfw2vVnnAKd3ChviPIscuQ3DgjlWxw7YUT/9FvfE1CkO@9/xM5h7F8x/pbHCkFVSEQlKeeRmJhKGJeFDJYSOpW0jvptfklUUHFWfVIwyH5JdBHfZwaG06N1VV2aySZC8Pp40pr@kUpWILPiWEp2oINzOccEdwv9MUMFI7hm@7e598hKCQietf2jtr3rKe3pocFshWfF5Efc//sMWwKa5Z@zlZwNydjtwchnIozCa8kvU4JBxQZPU@tPD8OJsOeDCF3/ctxST12RYAEGFQNiQzC7xZbrTIMhqNhBMPJMAzDXUI8PyIYRfAg10iun/sfswimk/3iXj5/@WX6Hw)

Comment: `if k<1:<code1> else:<code2>` can be shortened as `if k:<code2> else:<code1>` for -2 bytes.  `x==-1and-1` => `-(x==-1)` saves 2 more bytes.  `while c[3]and c[2]!=0:` => `while c[3]and c[2]:` => `while all(c[2:4]):` saves 4 bytes

Comment: I just found a -7 bytes ^^ : `else:while all(c[2:4]):c=c[3]` =>`while k<all(c[2:4]):c=c[3]`. The condition will always be false if `k>0` wich saves the `else`

Comment: @Jakque oh that is clever. thanks

Comment: ok last more thing : `c[1]=[p,c[1]][a];c[2]=[c[2],p][a]`=>`c[1],c[2]=[p,c[1],c[2],p][a::2]` => `c[1:3]=[p,*c[1:3],p][a::2]` saves 7 more bytes

Comment: @Jakque ah, i figured that could be shortened a bit - good find

Comment: [196 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU7RboMwDHyGr3DhJSnpREq3SqH5ksiaUEbUCAQB0ZF9PQvpOtmy73yWfe5nuY9DtW1frQFDPBVpoqVXgmOhSjxWaWLGGTqwA3jFBQY9cfJEuhun46w6VobQWDdSK44HWdahFw1KFxatgU7oCNe77Vvobk3fE63O4oI0KFpVmP5pO/4fTVJpfP72@@9JxHMnfpBeeHZc2af09VTIdfcz22EJ3jdD2u@mJ3Zwj4XQt7l1faNbkuUZg6zMKKWb4gzeGeQMLjHzmB8vUDHg5YucY70@Kf4C), the biggest save is `c[1:3]=[p,*c[1:3],p][a::2]` -> `c[1+a]=p`.

Comment: 194 : `a=c[1]!=0;c[1+a]=p` +> `c[1+(c[1]!=0)]=p`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES10),  <s>90 80</s>  78 bytes

Uses `undefined` for an absent child.

```javascript
a=>(g=d=>(b[d]=b[d]||[]).push(x=a[p++])*x&&[++d,d].map(g))(p=0,b=[])&&b.flat()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU7RCoIwFH33K/YkWy6ZlhXE@gufxh6m28wwHanhg/9uNhkYRXA43HM599xzE0/R5o/SdNu6kWrSdBL0AgsqZ86Y5PRN48g4Ck3fXuFABTNBwNFm8H0WBBJLHt6FgQVC0FCCMzp7fT8LdSU6iKYUUNDXUumyVvLseXlTt02lwqopoIYswiDBIMVgb5FaHNywwyAiTsSWj4vkCH1F/doRYnMTF/LzkFhD7F6kq2FpdlqVmxH9iSLu5uPl9AI)

#### Commented

We recursively walk through the input array `a[]`, using the depth-first way. While doing so, we fill the array `b[]` where the values are organized by depth. At the end of the process, we just need to flatten `b[]` to get the final output.

```javascript
a =>                  // a[] = depth-first input
( g = d =>            // g is a recursive function taking a depth d
  (b[d] = b[d] || []) //   create b[d] if it doesn't exist
  .push(              //   and push the value ...
    x = a[p++]        //   ... stored in a[] at position p; increment p afterwards
  )                   //
  * x &&              //   if this value is defined:
    [++d, d].map(g)   //     do two recursive calls to g with d + 1
)(                    // initial call to g with:
  p = 0,              //   d = p = 0
  b = []              //   b[] initialized to an empty array
)                     //
&& b.flat()           // end of call: return a flattened version of b[]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>126 110</s> 84 bytes

```python
def f(a,d=0,L=[]):L+=[[]];L[d]+=a[:1];a.pop(0)and f(a,d+1)+f(a,d+1);return sum(L,[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU9LCsMgEN3nFJKVohTNpy0J3sAbiAuJhnZRI2kC7emtTUhIoCXwGIaZ95nx7@HWuTw0nbE8TdNgbAtaqInhlAguFaoE5lIqVQtpFOZaVkzV@uQ7DynSzsxszBBemrq3w9g78BwfUJBoEaJxYl@2gd8YlPj@7gbYQskIJVQh9HtJKQEFASUBdMV/8kTMJszcbKOLNteprhN24LfkFhvZeWnyqKf7nMvRfesh5e6Z8AE)

### How it works:

The main idea is to reconstruct the layers of the graph in `L`. To do that, we will be doing some recursion and store the current depth in `d`.

#### Ungolfed and commented version:

```python
def f(a, d=0, L=[]): # a is our array, d is the currend depth, L are the layers
    L += [[]]          # append an empty layer in L to avoid future IndexError
    L[d] += a[:1]      # add the root of our current tree in the right layer

    if a.pop(0) != 0:  # Remove the first element of our tree and check if it is a root of a sub tree
        f(a, d+1) +      # compute the first sub-tree (append the nodes to the layers and remove them)
        f(a, d+1)        # compute the second sub-tree (same)
      
    return sum(L,[])   # return the flatened list of the layers
```

### Note:

As the program use the variable `L` as a reference, re-use the function after its first call will not return the good result because `L` won't have been reinitialized.

edit : In my previous answer, I cared a lot about the length of the sub-trees to recurse `a` at the right indice but it is no longer the case since we discard the elements of a when we visit them. The consequence of that is that `a` is empty at the end of the function, but who cares in a golf challenge ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 88 bytes

```hs
(concat=<<).foldr(#)[]
0#a=[[0]]:a
x#(p:q:a)=([x]:p%q):a
(u:p)%(v:q)=(u++v):p%q
p%q=p++q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtLCsMgGIT3nkIIgV@0xfQJEle9QJYF60LS2obaRPMip681ZZjhY4Z5meH9cC5@TNNiiX3ftCMGi1XBjoyzQxJPOv1zzwr@h13yeSVNkE23W4S6a2szyrIkW9u5ew8ZURrxzEiluNbCoCUDL4IwRIJatPB5IKmFSXiSwyxC6idKZ7IuKFl6SkOM39o68xzi5nqpqh8)

#### also 88 bytes

```hs
(concat=<<).foldr(#)[]
0#a=[[0]]:a
x#(p:q:a)=([x]:zipWith(++)(p++([]<$q))(q++([]<$p))):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvLCsIwFAX3/YpAXdxLoqQ@ITQrf6A7hZhFqMYGY5s@FsWPN0aRYQ6zOY0ZHzfv49O4lkgSBtdOBCxRBdsxzrYJntj/dsMK/ot18vAtjZlNt0uEumtrM8myxJXt/HWAHJXOeG6kUlxrYbI5hyB6YVCCmrV4uXByUwOUIgRKQely0SNC/@@AiMLE@K6tN/cxLs/HqvoA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>118</s> <s>114</s> 113 bytes

```r
f=function(x,d=1,G=new.env()){G$g=c(G$g,d)
o=x[-1]
if(sum(o|1)&x)o=f(f(o,d+1,G),d+1,G)
`if`(d<2,x[order(G$g)],o)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCsIwEETv@YqAIruYSlMUejBe@xGlUGga6cEGqtWA@u0xNq3EwJCwO/uGGaxVQo19c@t0D4ZJwVkh@vaxa/s7ID6L9Vk04F4mkWhhyoRXpFNwHS@gXxw3BrVQoEAzuXUszh@pO1WDPGbMlHqQ7fDNwIppfFsFHOmKJidaujAFDXBGUyf8rf1MZzd1w57Rg9/Gt7ObhgcLOO2ySd7JggwH5QvqFfTw0RO/X7B8uvBxIRYrqB03/68duxWxHw)

**The idea**

Traverse the array by reviving the DFS and keeping track of the visited recursion depths; then use the depths to order the array BFS-wise.

**Unrolled code and explanation:**

```r
f=function(       # function args:
     x,           #  - vector x
     d=1,         #  - current recursion depth d (default=1)
     G=new.env()  #  - a passed-by-reference obj (enviroment)
     ){
  G$g=c(G$g,d)    # concat curr.depth to vector of depths
                  # (the vector is a var. inside the enviroment, initially NULL)
  o=x[-1]         # remove first element of x storing the result in o
  if(sum(o|1)&x){ # if o has elements and the first element of x > 0
    o=f(o,d+1,G)  #  recurse on left branch increasing d and updating o
    o=f(o,d+1,G)  #  recurse on right branch increasing d and updating o
  }
  if(d<2){        # if d == 1
    x[order(G$g)] #  use the stored depths to reorder x and return it
  }else{          # else
    o             #  return o
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 bytes

```
Ḣ;ß},ß}ɗ¥WAƑ?
J×ṠÇAœiⱮJẈż$Ụị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkXWh@fX6gDxyemHloY7Hptoz@V1ePrDnQsOtzsenZz5aOM6r4e7Oo7uUXm4e8nD3d3/j056uHOG9aOGOQq6dgqPGuZaH24HC6lwATnKOkAJXUMgAeRUuh2dFHa4/f9/JSWlaEMdBVMdBWUdBRMwUgYjMxjDWEfB0ADGMQKT5hBuLFAzAA)

Uses `-1` for an absent child. This recreates a binary tree of the list indices and then sorts the original list based on the depth and position of the indices.

### Explanation

#### Helper link

Takes a list of integers representing a depth-first binary tree and recursively turns it into a representation of that tree using nested lists

```
Ḣ             | Head
          AƑ? | If non-negative:
        ¥     | - Then:
 ;            |   - Concatenate to:
  ß},ß}ɗ      |   - The results of calling this link recursively using the remainder of the list, pairing the results of each call together
         W    | - Else: wrap in a list
```

#### Main link

```
J              | Sequence along list
 ×Ṡ            | Multiplied by the signs of the original list
   Ç           | Call helper link
    A          | Absolute
     œiⱮJ      | Find multi-dimensional indices of each list index
         Ẉż$   | Prepend the list lengths (i.e. depth)
            Ụ  | Indices required for this sort order
             ị | Index into original list
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 80 bytes

```r
for(i in x<-scan()){F=c(F,T);T=T+(i>0)*T+!i;while(!T%%2+i)T=T/2};x[order(F[-1])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/RasMwDHzfV6iUgrQ4zHbTrZC2j/kCvwU/lCxhhpEUt6OB0m/PUrte3cDgMJZ0dzrZoYFNCs1PW51M12JPcIFjtW@futTDXNXHE5zt/nCo7dB0Fg2YFvpNemMj0aXYVlgwRbnaqgTNjtOrSmYmP3@Z7xpnarGQiaFx@CaveV929rO2WJSp0KSH60uDFQoGKwacQebAHd7DZ8lA8FBI9374kgjmkO6g9AbL4CE8MYtMHqIYelwv/kx0CDP1vtVwn3K/YhXbPLj3KY8JQeh6MpzAo48XraPjR0Q5vLXTZ0G2dgwZDuX/IYo9Tf4cezrVwy8)

Full program, takes leaf nodes as \$0\$. Runs through the input and keeps track of the current depth in the following way:

- Store the current value of depth accumulator `T` (preinitialized to \$1\$) in `F`.
- If the current node is positive, move to the next level (multiply `T` by 2).
- Otherwise increase `T` by 1. If after this addition, `T` is divisible by 2, we've already had two child nodes in this level, and need to keep backing up (divide `T` by 2) until it is no longer divisible.

In other words, we can imagine `T` as a binary number, where each bit represents a level, \$0\$ is its first branch, and \$1\$ is its second branch. Moving to a new level is equivalent to adding another zero bit, and when the number "wraps around" all trailing zeroes are removed. For example, in the demo input:

`[1, 5, #, 4, 4, #, #, 6, #, #, 3, ...]`

```r
Input     Next depth     
          1
1     ->  10
5     ->  100
0     ->  101
4     ->  1010
4     ->  10100
0     ->  10101
0     ->  1011
6     ->  10110
0     ->  10111
0     ->  11    
3     ->  110
...
```

Finally, return x sorted in the order of `F`.

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü§!■YΦ─Ä↓Θ½(-²9♂^♀_¡#{Σ├j↨à,lqƒ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=811521fe59e8c48e19e9ab282dfd390b5e0c5fad237be4c36a17852c6c719f&i=%5B1,0,0%5D%0A%5B1,+5,+0,+4,+4,+0,+0,+6,+0,+0,+3,+10,+0,+0,+2,+0,+7,+0,+0%5D%0A%5B100,+4,+5,+0,+0,+0,+0%5D%0A&m=2)

null nodes are represented by `0`, and are required in the input in all places applicable.

parses the given traversal into a nested list, and then flattens it into layers. The parsing part is actually much smaller than the portion which prints the layers, somehow.

Golfed a bit with some help from recursive.

### Explanation

```
Gd{c{|4!fsn|-:f:fcwLr$J}Bsn!CGG~2l]+,
| printing             || parsing   |

Bsn!CGG~2l]+,
B               remove first element and push
 sn!C           if zero, stop recursion
    GG          do 2 recursive calls
      ~         move array to input stack
        2l]+    create a pair from the recursive calls, prepend previous iteration
            ,   retrieve array from input stack

Gd{c{|4!fsn|-:f:fcwLr$J}
G                      } run after recursive operation is over
 d                       delete empty list
  {              cw      run as long as tree isn't empty
   c{|4!f                copy, get elements at depth 0
         sn|-            remove those from the original tree
             :f:f        flatten twice
                   Lr    put all levels in a list
                     $   flatten
                      J  join with spaces
```